# How to implement simple sessions for Google App Engine?

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, session, cookies

Here is a very basic class for handling sessions on App Engine:

```
"""Lightweight implementation of cookie-based sessions for Google App Engine.

Classes:
Session

"""

import os
import random
import Cookie
from google.appengine.api import memcache

_COOKIE_NAME = 'app-sid'
_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
_SESSION_EXPIRE_TIME = 180 * 60


class Session(object):

    """Cookie-based session implementation using Memcached."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.sid = None
        self.key = None
        self.session = None
        cookie_str = os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE', '')
        self.cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        self.cookie.load(cookie_str)
        if self.cookie.get(_COOKIE_NAME):
            self.sid = self.cookie[_COOKIE_NAME].value
            self.key = 'session-' + self.sid
            self.session = memcache.get(self.key)
        if self.session:
            self._update_memcache()
        else:
            self.sid = str(random.random())[5:] + str(random.random())[5:]
            self.key = 'session-' + self.sid
            self.session = dict()
            memcache.add(self.key, self.session, _SESSION_EXPIRE_TIME)
            self.cookie[_COOKIE_NAME] = self.sid
            self.cookie[_COOKIE_NAME]['path'] = _COOKIE_PATH
            print self.cookie

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.session)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.session:
            return self.session[key]
        raise KeyError(str(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.session[key] = value
        self._update_memcache()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.session:
            del self.session[key]
            self._update_memcache()
            return None
        raise KeyError(str(key))

    def __contains__(self, item):
        try:
            i = self.__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            return False
        return True

    def _update_memcache(self):
        memcache.replace(self.key, self.session, _SESSION_EXPIRE_TIME)
```

I would like some advices on how to improve the code for better security.

**Note:** In the production version it will also save a copy of the session in the datastore.

**Note':** I know there are much more complete implementations available online though I would like to learn more about this subject so please don't answer the question with "use that" or "use the other" library.

Comment: Any chance you'd be interested in open sourcing the implementation you came up with?  I think a lot of people would find this very useful.

Comment: Sorry, I did this a long time ago for a client and I no longer have access to that code. However, I think that better solutions may have popped up in the more recent years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for simplifying your implementation.

You are creating a randomized temporary key that you use as the session's key in the memcache.  You note that you will be storing the session in the datastore as well (where it will have another key).

Why not randomize the session's datastore key, and then use that as the one and only key, for both the database and the memcache (if necessary)?  Does this simplification introduce any new security issues?

Here's some code for creating a randomized datastore key for the Session model:

```
# Get a random integer to use as the session's datastore ID.
# (So it can be stored in a cookie without being 'guessable'.)
random.seed();
id = None;
while None==id or Session.get_by_id( id ):
    id = random.randrange( sys.maxint );
seshKey = db.Key.from_path( 'Session', id );    
session = Session( key = seshKey );
```

To get the ID from the session (i.e. to store in the cookie) use:

```
sid = session.key().id();
```

To retrieve the session instance after the 'sid' has been read from the cookie:

```
session = Session.get_by_id( sid );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of additional security measures you could add.

First, I think it is pretty common to use information stored in the session instance to validate each new request.  For example, you could verify that the IP address and user-agent don't change during a session:

```
newip = str( request.remote_addr );
if sesh.ip_addr != newip:
    logging.warn( "Session IP has changed to %s." % newip);
newua = rh.request.headers.get( 'User-Agent', None );
if sesh.agent != newua:
    logging.warn( "Session UA has changed to %s." % newua );
```

Also, perhaps it would be better to prevent the session from being renewed indefinitely?  I think that sites such as Google will eventually ask you to sign-in again if you try to keep a session going for a long time.

I guess it would be easy to slowly decrease the _SESSION_EXPIRE_TIME each time the session gets renewed, but that isn't really a very good solution.  Ideally the choice of when to force the user to sign-in again would take into account the flow and security requirements of your site.

Comment: Checking IP may not be a great idea - clients could be multi-homed or they could have a weird ISP like [AOL which apparently changes the client's IP pretty often]("http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2004/03/03/notes-on-php-session-security/").  Though if you aren't too worried about these annoyances for your users (perhaps they are sufficiently uncommon), then it would make it difficult for an attacker to use a hijacked session id.

Checking the User-Agent could make things harder for the attacker, but if they've stolen your session id from your cookie then they probably know your User-Agent too.